# How to create a function that returns a random number from the LEVY distribution in Lua?

Tags: random, lua, distribution

As the title says, is there an easy function I can make in Lua that draws a random number based on the **Levy probability density function**?

I'm planning on using Levy-flight to make particles explore (make large steps) in a search space more efficiently.

Comment: Have you tried something? How much understanding do you have of the Levy pdf?

Comment: I don't really know how to start structuring the code for that type of RNG. I basically know how the Levy pdf is expressed. And ofc just some basic knowledge of the distribution compared to other (such as gaussian). Just enough to know what I want to do with it!

Comment: Use rejection sampling on the graph of the PDF.

Comment: I've added an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered. You may want to add your own answer, ideally with Lua code if you can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) on the graph of the [Lévy PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_distribution) [answer from user: lhf]

Example of code:

```
function rejectionSampling()
repeat 
    local x = random.uniform(1)
    local y = random.uniform(1.5)       -- PDF maximum peak at x=1/3 --> y~1.45
    fx = math.sqrt(1/(2*math.pi))*math.exp(-1/(2*x))/(x^1.5)  --PDF
until y < fx

return x
end
```

Comment: You probably want to declare `x` and `y` as local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) on the graph of the [Lévy PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be :

1. give a lecture to [John Nolan RobustAnalysis](http://www.robustanalysis.com/)
2. buy/try the C library, here is the [documentation](http://www.robustanalysis.com/CUserManual.pdf).
3. use luaJit ffi library and map c functions and data structure to lua.

...it's no difficult but you need time.

Outside lua (*yes I know the question was on lua*), but you could try an interaction between lua and Wolfram Mathematica, where stable distribution are [built-in](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/HeavyTailDistributions.html).